# How to set default javascript syntax in Atom?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I am using the Atom text editor, and for the longest time the syntax highlighting was working perfectly. Then I upgraded atom, and it changed the default syntax from `JavaScript (rails)` to just `JavaScript` syntax highlighting. Now I manually have to change it everytime I open a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a while, I found something that works well. In Atom go to

> Atom > Init script

Then add the following code

```
path = require 'path'

atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) ->
    if path.extname(editor.getPath()) == ".js"
        editor.setGrammar(atom.grammars.grammarForScopeName('source.js.rails source.js.jquery'))
```

In this case I am setting the default syntax highlight for all files ending in `.js` to my preferred syntax `source.js.rails source.js.jquery`

You can find the source name of the syntax you want by manually going to the syntax highlighting, and it will be listed next to the name on the right

[image: Atom Syntax Selector]